# Scrapy is throwing URL error

Tags: python, mongodb, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to design a web crawler for scraping data from flipkart. I am using mongoDB to store the data. My code is as follows:

WebSpider.py

```
from scrapy.spider import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from spider_web.items import SpiderWebItem

class WebSpider(CrawlSpider):
     name = "spider_web"
     allowed_domains = ["http://www.flipkart.com"]
     start_urls = [
           "http://www.flipkart.com/search?q=amish+tripathi",
     ]
     def parse(self, response):
          books = response.selector.xpath(
             '//div[@class="old-grid"]/div[@class="gd-row browse-grid-row"]')

    for book in books:
        item = SpiderWebItem()

        item['title'] = book.xpath(
            './/div[@class="pu-details lastUnit"]/div[@class="pu-title fk-font-13"]/a[contains(@href, "from-search")]/@title').extract()[0].strip()

        item['rating'] = book.xpath(
            './/div[@class="pu-details lastUnit"]/div[@class="pu-rating"]/div[1]/@title').extract()[0]

        item['noOfRatings'] = book.xpath(
            './/div[@class="pu-details lastUnit"]/div[@class="pu-rating"]/text()').extract()[1].strip()

        item['url'] = response.url

        yield item
```

items.py

```
 from scrapy.item import Item, Field

 class SpiderWebItem(Item):
     url = Field()
     title = Field()
     rating = Field()
     noOfRatings = Field()
```

pipelines.py

```
 import pymongo

 from scrapy.conf import settings
 from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
 from scrapy import log


 class MongoDBPipeline(object):

      def __init__(self):
          connection = pymongo.MongoClient(
               settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
               settings['MONGODB_PORT']
          )
          db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
          self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

     def process_item(self, item, spider):
         for data in item:
              if not data:
                 raise DropItem("Missing data!")
         self.collection.update({'title': item['title']}, dict(item), upsert=True)
         log.msg("book added to MongoDB database!",
            level=log.DEBUG, spider=spider)
         return item
```

settings.py
     BOT_NAME = 'spider_web'

```
 SPIDER_MODULES = ['spider_web.spiders']
 NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'spider_web.spiders'
 DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
      's3': None,
 }
 DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 0.25
 DEPTH_PRIORITY = 1
 SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue'
 SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE = 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'
 ITEM_PIPELINES = ['spider_web.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline', ]

 MONGODB_SERVER = "localhost"
 MONGODB_PORT = 27017
 MONGODB_DB = "flipkart"
 MONGODB_COLLECTION = "books"
```

I have checked every xpath with scrapy shell. they are yielding correct result. But the start_URL is throwing . The error when I run the spider is:

```
2015-10-05 20:05:10 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.flipkart.com/search?q=rabindranath+tagore> (
referer: None)

........

  File "F:\myP\Web Scraping\spider_web\spider_web\spiders\WebSpider.py", line 21, in parse
    './/div[@class="pu-details lastUnit"]/div[@class="pu-rating"]/div[1]/@title').extract()[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am at my wits end here. The spider is fetching data for an item or two and then raising an error and the spider is stopping all together. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are *books without ratings*, you need to handle them too. For instance:

```
try:
    item['rating'] = book.xpath('.//div[@class="pu-details lastUnit"]/div[@class="pu-rating"]/div[1]/@title').extract()[0]
except IndexError:
    item['rating'] = 'no rating'
```

But, I would actually think about using [Item Loaders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) with input and output processors and let them handle these situations.